# For What Families of Subgraphs, the Subgraph Isomorphism Problem Can be Solved in Polynomial Time?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, graph-isomorphism

Are there families of subgraphs that are arbitrarily large and are still easy to match in a larger graph ? By a "family" I mean a graph sequence $\mathcal{G}=\{G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_n,\ldots\}$ which is generated by a polynomial time algorithm and the total size of the graphs increase monotonically $|V_n|+|E_n|\ge|V_{n-1}|+|E_{n-1}|$ (this can be relaxed in many ways). Other than trivial cases like paths and cycles, I suspect there are other sequences (hopefully with automorphism groups of various size).